# Will Windows 10 Technical Preview be upgradable to final release?

Tags: windows-10-preview

Is there any information about if Windows 10 Technical Preview will then be upgradable to the final release ?

I'm asking that because I would like to use it on my primary PC (I'm aware of the risks but I accept them), in place of Windows 8.1 But I'd like to avoid to reinstall all after the release of the final version.

Comment: I thnik this will depend on what microsoft will change. We can spaculate a lot but only microsoft will be able to anwser this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to Gabriel Aul, a  member of the Windows 10 development team, it is Microsoft's intention to make this possible.

On December 5, someone asked Gabriel Aul the following question on twitter.

> will we be able to update to the RTM version when it ships from the TP
>   branch?

Mr. Aul responded with the following response

> Yes, that is our intent.

[Source](https://twitter.com/gabeaul/status/540579810880147457)

Comment: Please add a source if you find one. It would improve your answer

Comment: Source: https://twitter.com/gabeaul/status/540579810880147457

Comment: @Overmind - I went ahead and tried to improve your answer to better match the type of answer we are looking for.  It was a great answer except for the use of "M$" which just isn't appropriate.

Comment: Even if g's reply is eventually correct, there's no reason to be encouraged that it will be in the way you might want. It was true for the 8.1 preview's initial upgrades to final, but with [heavy caveats](http://superuser.com/revisions/612406/2)...

Comment: Agreed; its a basic rule since windows. It's better to install all-at-once than upgrade step by step.