# Will the "Get Windows 10" offer pop up on a machine which ran Windows 7 before being upgraded to Windows 10 Tech Preview?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-preview, windows-10-upgrade

I had Windows 7 running on a PC of mine and wanted to try out the Win 10 Tech Preview. I installed the Tech Preview as an upgrade to my Windows 7 installation, not a clean install. Now, my other PCs, which still run Win 7, are all offering me a free upgrade to Win 10 when it comes out, but the PC which is running the Tech Preview isn't. All the PCs are up to date on Windows Update. Does anyone know if a machine that was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10 Tech Preview should/will get the "Get Windows 10" offer? If not, I'll go ahead and restore my Windows 7 image to that PC.

Comment: @Ramhound "You opting into Insider Preview is outside of the offer to upgrade to the retail release of Windows 10". I haven't read that anywhere, that's why I'm asking the question. It seems to me that since Windows 7 was installed on the machine before I upgraded to the Win10 Tech Preview, the offer should still come up.

Comment: why the downvote? As far as I can tell, this question hasn't been asked.

Comment: @DanC: Read [this](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-technical-preview-users-should-be-able-upgrade-rtm-version-windows-10).

Comment: @Ramhound "Your not running the technical preview" Huh? I explicitly stated that I was in the question. The Tech Preview and the Insider Preview are the same thing, when it was first offered by Microsoft it was called the Technical Preview, now it's the Insider Preview.   "the upgrade offer, is again separate from the technical preview" You already said that, but haven't shown any kind of source or proof for that assertion. If you can, and submit that as an answer, that would answer the question.

Comment: @Karan Thanks. I knew I'd be able to upgrade, what I was getting at in the question was this: MS is offering free upgrades to Win7 users with the "Get Windows 10" tray icon. It doesn't seem like they're making the same offer to Win7 users who installed the Win10 Tech Preview/Insider Preview.

Comment: @DanC - No; Because Windows 10 Technical Preview users don't get a free license, they can upgrade to [RTM](http://superuser.com/questions/871051/will-windows-10-technical-preview-be-upgradable-to-final-release?rq=1), they will just need to provide a valid license after words.

Comment: @DanC: Basically what Ramhound said. At this point though we don't know in what way Tech/Insider Preview users who upgrade to RTM will be able to provide a valid Win7/8 license so that Win10 gets activated successfully.